# linux system(3) call fails - how to know the errno-like error code?

Tags: linux, errno, system-calls

When I call the system(char* Command) with some command and it fails, I should like to know the error code (and not to parse text output).
For example, I run system("rm file") and 'file' does not exist - how can I receive ENOENT into my application?

Answer (score 4):

You can only do this is the command explicitly returns that status.

```
rc = system(...);
if (rc != -1 && WIFEXITED(rc))
    printf("Terminated with status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rc));
```

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  `fork(2)` failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is 
>   in  the format  specified  in `wait(2)`.  Thus, the exit code of the
>   command will be `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.

But if the command simply returns `1` when something goes wrong it's hard for the caller to tell the actual reason.